# curl post data and file contemporary

Tags: post, curl

I have tried:

`curl -v --http1.0 --data "mac=00:00:00" -F "userfile=@/tmp/02-02-02-02-02-22" http://url_address/getfile.php`

but it fails with the following message:
`Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!`

How can I send a mix of data and file by `curl`? Is it possible or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on how [-F](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) actually works! You can add any number of data parts and file parts in a multipart formpost that `-F` makes. `-d` however makes a "standard" clean post and you cannot mix `-d` with `-F`.

You need to first figure out which kind of post you want, then you pick *either* `-d` or `-F` depending on your answer.